# Objective-c regex checking for sequence of two numbers

Tags: objective-c, regex

Can't seem to figure out how to check a string so that the same two characters in a row are not allowed.

I don't want anyone to be able to submit data with "00".

Comment: While this is possible with a complicated regex, why not just take the simple approach and loop through the characters making sure the same one doesn't appear twice in a row?

Comment: Is "00" the *only* thing that you want to detect, or are you also looking for "11", "22"..."99"?

Comment: Just "00" don't want a credit card date to contain "00/00" or "00/13"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about just:

```
(\d)\1+
```

The `\d` matches any digit and the `\1+` matches whatever was matched in the first bit when it appears more than one time.

---

Pertaining to your comments though, it's much easier just to check:

```
if ([expiryDate rangeOfString:@"00"].location != NSNotFound)
{
    //Invalid date
}
```

or even perhaps more validating:

```
NSArray *components = [expiryDate componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
int month = [components[0] intValue];
int year = [components[1] intValue];
NSAssert(month > 0 && month <= 12, @"Invalid Month");
NSAssert(year >= 13 /*current year*/ /* (optionally) && year < 20 (or some other future year)*/, @"Invalid year");
```